# Codeigniter controller number to word converter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to convert any number to words using my Codeigniter Controller.

My Controller as follows :

```
public function convert_number_to_words($number)
    {

    $hyphen = ' ';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator = ' ';
    $negative = 'negative ';
    $decimal = ' and Cents ';
    $dictionary = array(
        0 => 'Zero',
        1 => 'One',
        2 => 'Two',
        3 => 'Three',
        4 => 'Four',
        5 => 'Five',
        6 => 'Six',
        7 => 'Seven',
        8 => 'Eight',
        9 => 'Nine',
        10 => 'Ten',
        11 => 'Eleven',
        12 => 'Twelve',
        13 => 'Thirteen',
        14 => 'Fourteen',
        15 => 'Fifteen',
        16 => 'Sixteen',
        17 => 'Seventeen',
        18 => 'Eighteen',
        19 => 'Nineteen',
        20 => 'Twenty',
        30 => 'Thirty',
        40 => 'Fourty',
        50 => 'Fifty',
        60 => 'Sixty',
        70 => 'Seventy',
        80 => 'Eighty',
        90 => 'Ninety',
        100 => 'Hundred',
        1000 => 'Thousand',
        1000000 => 'Million',
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . $this->convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens = ((int)($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int)($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = $this->convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string)$fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}

public function printWord(){

$numberToWord = $this->Number_model->getNumber();

$this->amount_word = $this->convert_number_to_words($numberToWord ) . " Only ***";  

    }
```

The model named "Number_model" returns the number in digits correctly. After that it should be printed using following php code in the view.

```
<?=$this->amount_word?>
```

## Desired Result

I need to print that number, into words using `<?=$this->amount_word?>` in my view. But it shows -> Only *** without the converted number in words.

I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: your code works, if you try for example `echo $this->convert_number_to_words(61222);die;` so the question is how to you call your view in the controller? and mainly check, if $numbertoWord is a valid number, so check the model Number_model->getNumber()

Comment: @Vickel. the model Number_model->getNumber()  is working fine. It returns the number

Comment: so check how you "feed" the view with the result of `convert_number_to_words`, which is not clear from your example code

Comment: @Vickel. It is <p style="position: absolute;top: 20cm;right: 8cm"> <?=$this->amount_word?></p>

Comment: I've just checked, I call from my controller index method $this->printWord(); then I call the view; the view echos out correctly... (I've hardcoded $numberToWord)

Comment: @Vickel. But my view still outs the empty result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200130/discussion-between-vickel-and-mcit-trends).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code in your example works with an hardcoded number and the view returns the concatenated string `"Only ***"` the problem is most likely that the model's function `$this->Number_model->getNumber();` is returning an array. therefore you need to address your function to use a value from this array:

if the array (use `print_r($numberToWord)` to see how the array looks like) for example is:

Array
(
    [0] => 1234
)

we can use:

```
$this->amount_word = $this->convert_number_to_words($numberToWord[0] )
```

**update from  comments:**

as the array looks like:

Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[fuel_qty] => 30
)
)

and want to address fuel_qty, we need to send the array's object value like this:

```
$this->convert_number_to_words($numberToWord[0]->fuel_qty)
```

where `[0]` is the array index and `->fuel_qty` the object's key